# UART receiving in linux

Tags: linux, interrupt, uart, isr

This is mainly a conceptual question.

I have a ARM board receiving data from an external device through UART. It can send and receive data just fine (through /dev/ttyS1)

But to receive data, I have to explicitly use the 'read' or 'cat' command from terminal.

I'm trying to figure out how can I have an interrupt to receive the data and save the incoming data without using the read command. I was thinking of writing a C program to use poll() perpetually, but was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

If polling is the only way, is there a tutorial on this?

Comment: What do you expect the system to do with the data if nothing is listening?

Comment: So right now system only listens for the data only when it is required. Otherwise it does not react to the data from serial at all. But I plan to change this so that it reacts to interrupts.

Comment: The interrupt is already handled by the kernel.

Comment: True, I was looking for ways to utilize that interrupt in a program.

Comment: But... why? That's not your problem. Use `select()` like everyone else does.